# Fixing [young-adult] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, the information on [young-adult](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-adult) reads:

> This tag should be used for questions about fiction that is intended
>   for readers approximately aged between 16 and 25. A common
>   abbreviation is YA.

This is incorrect.  Young adult books are aimed at teenagers.  Most sources give the age range as 12-18, though some are different by a year in either direction.  In no case is the age range anything near 16-25.  (Note: anyone of any age can (and does) read YA books but the age range here is the industry standard.)

Sources:

- [SFWA](https://www.sfwa.org/2013/02/an-introduction-to-middle-grade-and-young-adult-fiction-part-1-definitions/)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_adult_fiction)

There is also a recent category called [New Adult](https://www.publishersweekly.com/pw/by-topic/industry-news/publisher-news/article/63285-new-adult-matures.html), for ages 18-25.  I would have no objections to adding a tag for this, if it seems useful.

**I have enough rep to change the tag unilaterally, but I'm posting here first to make sure no one objects.  If I don't get any objections in a couple days, I'll go ahead and make the change.**  I'll also update the info on [children](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) and [middle-grade](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-grade) to point people to the correct tags by age.

Comment: Sounds right to me. And you're doing an impressive job adding the age-appropriate tags where they're needed.

Comment: Thanks @Galastel (and thanks for catching my whoops on not formatting the tags correctly).  I've started to do some retags of old posts in preparation for really fixing this all up.  I stopped after one page of results as not to completely overwhelm the question queue.  There's a lot of bad tagging around!  (not even counting the retags needed because of tags added or changed after the question was posted)

Answer (score 3):

I have revamped the following tags:

[children](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children)
[middle-grade](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-grade)
[young-adult](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-adult)
[child-characters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-characters)
[young-author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-author)

Sample usage guidance:

> This tag should be used for questions about writing intended for
>   readers between 12 and 18 years old. (Often abbreviated YA.) For
>   readers ages 8-12 use [middle-grade]. For readers under 8 use
>   [children].

Sample full tag wiki (each only lists the needed alternate tags):

> For readers under 8 use [children](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children)
>  For readers ages 8-12 use
>   [middle-grade](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-grade)
>  For readers ages 12-18 use
>   [young-adult](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-adult)
>  For questions about characters who are children
>   (especially in adult books), use [child-characters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-characters)
>   For questions
>   about children or teens who are writers, use [young-author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-author)

Note that I removed the possibility of [children](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) being about children who write, because it was confusing and also a dup with the pre-existing [young-author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-author).

[child-characters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-characters) is more or less the same, I just added information to make it consistent with the others.  I also did not change anything about [middle-grade](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-grade) or [young-author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-author) or the basic definition of [children](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children)

All of the tags refer to each other so questioners can easily differentiate.

Please check for errors.  I worked hard to eliminate them, but might have missed something.

Comment: And sorry for the flood of edited posts but I am now done with anything I found in a search with "children", "teen", or "middle grade."  I'm sure there will be more in the future though.

Comment: In response to the [tag confusion on this question today](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43540/how-to-write-cleanly-even-if-my-character-uses-expletive-language), isn't middle-grade in the US mostly 7th-8th grade?  (Sometimes 6th or 9th are included.) 8 -12 looks more like 3rd - 6th grade, which is elementary school, so I can see why the poster didn't consider searching for the middle-grade tag.

Comment: Unless the tag is not actually referring to the "middle-grade" school level, but then I'm not familiar with the "middle-grade" category of literature and don't recall it being separated out as such in bookstores and libraries.

Comment: @Troyen Middle Grade is a well known and well-used publishing category that refers to materials for children ages 8-12 (the exact age can vary a bit).  You are thinking of Middle *School* which is 6th-8th grade (compared to Junior High which is 7th-9th, though these days there is some flexibility and either can be anything from 6th to 9th).  The other poster could have found [tag:middle-grade] by searching for "young" or "child."  The tag doesn't pop up but the other tags describe each other in their wiki guidance.